# FlexSPI erase and write issue on NXP 2160A-TCD platform

Tags: spi

We encounter FLEXSPI erase and write issue. We use the following commands to test FLEXSPI read, write, and erase.

```
mtd_debug erase /dev/mtd2 0x0000000 0x10000
dd if=/dev/zero of=data.hex count=1 bs=65536
mtd_debug write /dev/mtd2 0x0000000 0x10000 data.hex
mtd_debug read /dev/mtd2 0x0000000 0x10000 dump
```

The contents of data.hex and dump files should be same. But unfortunately the contents of these two files are not identical.

spi-nxp-fspi.c is FLEXSPI driver source file.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by disabling erasing and writing protection from NOR flash register.